# Tabular varias columnas de un dataframe según una variable (columna) "Año"

Tags: r

Intento tabular un dataframe,

Tengo varias columnas
`c("Año","Municipio","Población","Esfuerzo Social","Esfuerzo Total")`

El resultado buscado para cada `municipio` es una columna por año de las variables `Población, Esfuerzo Social y Esfuerzo Total`, es decir, para cada variable `Población, Esfuerzo Social y Esfuerzo Total` ha de haber una columna para cada uno de los valores de la variable `Año`

Este es el dataframe:

```
structure(list(`Código Municipio INE` = c("02003", "02003", "02003", 
"03014", "03014", "03014", "04013", "04013", "04013", "05019", 
"05019", "06015", "06015", "06015", "07040", "07040", "07040", 
"08019", "08019", "08019", "09059", "09059", "09059", "10037", 
"10037", "10037", "11012", "11012", "11012", "12040", "12040", 
"12040", "13034", "13034", "13034", "14021", "14021", "14021", 
"15030", "15030", "15030", "16078", "16078", "16078", "17079", 
"17079", "17079", "18087", "18087", "18087", "19130", "19130", 
"19130", "21041", "21041", "21041", "22125", "22125", "22125", 
"23050", "23050", "23050", "24089", "24089", "24089", "25120", 
"25120", "25120", "26089", "26089", "26089", "27028", "27028", 
"27028", "28079", "28079", "28079", "29067", "29067", "29067", 
"30030", "30030", "30030", "32054", "32054", "32054", "33044", 
"33044", "33044", "34120", "34120", "34120", "35016", "35016", 
"35016", "36038", "36038", "36038", "37274", "37274", "37274", 
"38038", "38038", "38038", "39075", "39075", "39075", "40194", 
"40194", "40194", "41091", "41091", "41091", "42173", "42173", 
"42173", "43148", "43148", "43148", "44216", "44216", "44216", 
"45168", "45168", "45168", "46250", "46250", "46250", "47186", 
"47186", "47186", "49275", "49275", "49275", "50297", "50297", 
"50297", "51001", "51001", "51001", "52001", "52001", "52001"
), Año = c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017"
), Municipio = c("Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Alicante/Alacant", 
"Alicante/Alacant", "Alicante/Alacant", "Almería", "Almería", 
"Almería", "Ávila", "Ávila", "Badajoz", "Badajoz", "Badajoz", 
"Palma", "Palma", "Palma", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
"Burgos", "Burgos", "Burgos", "Cáceres", "Cáceres", "Cáceres", 
"Cádiz", "Cádiz", "Cádiz", "Castellón de la Plana/Castelló de la Plana", 
"Castellón de la Plana/Castelló de la Plana", "Castellón de la Plana/Castelló de la Plana", 
"Ciudad Real", "Ciudad Real", "Ciudad Real", "Córdoba", "Córdoba", 
"Córdoba", "Coruña (A)", "Coruña (A)", "Coruña (A)", "Cuenca", 
"Cuenca", "Cuenca", "Girona", "Girona", "Girona", "Granada", 
"Granada", "Granada", "Guadalajara", "Guadalajara", "Guadalajara", 
"Huelva", "Huelva", "Huelva", "Huesca", "Huesca", "Huesca", "Jaén", 
"Jaén", "Jaén", "León", "León", "León", "Lleida", "Lleida", "Lleida", 
"Logroño", "Logroño", "Logroño", "Lugo", "Lugo", "Lugo", "Madrid", 
"Madrid", "Madrid", "Málaga", "Málaga", "Málaga", "Murcia", "Murcia", 
"Murcia", "Ourense", "Ourense", "Ourense", "Oviedo", "Oviedo", 
"Oviedo", "Palencia", "Palencia", "Palencia", "Palmas de Gran Canaria (Las)", 
"Palmas de Gran Canaria (Las)", "Palmas de Gran Canaria (Las)", 
"Pontevedra", "Pontevedra", "Pontevedra", "Salamanca", "Salamanca", 
"Salamanca", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", 
"Santa Cruz de Tenerife", "Santander", "Santander", "Santander", 
"Segovia", "Segovia", "Segovia", "Sevilla", "Sevilla", "Sevilla", 
"Soria", "Soria", "Soria", "Tarragona", "Tarragona", "Tarragona", 
"Teruel", "Teruel", "Teruel", "Toledo", "Toledo", "Toledo", "Valencia", 
"Valencia", "Valencia", "Valladolid", "Valladolid", "Valladolid", 
"Zamora", "Zamora", "Zamora", "Zaragoza", "Zaragoza", "Zaragoza", 
"Ceuta", "Ceuta", "Ceuta", "Melilla", "Melilla", "Melilla"), 
    Población = c(172121L, 172426L, 172816L, 328648L, 330525L, 
    329988L, 194203L, 194515L, 195389L, 58083L, 58149L, 149892L, 
    149946L, 150543L, 400578L, 402949L, 406492L, 1604555L, 1608746L, 
    1620809L, 177100L, 176608L, 175623L, 95617L, 95814L, 95917L, 
    120468L, 118919L, 118048L, 171669L, 170990L, 169498L, 74427L, 
    74054L, 74641L, 327362L, 326609L, 325916L, 243870L, 243978L, 
    244099L, 55428L, 55102L, 54876L, 97586L, 98255L, 99013L, 
    235800L, 234758L, 232770L, 83391L, 83633L, 84145L, 146318L, 
    145468L, 145115L, 52239L, 52282L, 52223L, 115395L, 114658L, 
    114238L, 127817L, 126192L, 125317L, 138542L, 138144L, 137327L, 
    151344L, 150876L, 150979L, 98134L, 98268L, 97995L, 3141991L, 
    3165541L, 3182981L, 569130L, 569009L, 569002L, 439889L, 441003L, 
    443243L, 106231L, 105893L, 105636L, 221870L, 220567L, 220301L, 
    79595L, 79137L, 78892L, 379766L, 378998L, 377650L, 82539L, 
    82549L, 82671L, 146438L, 144949L, 144436L, 203811L, 203585L, 
    203692L, 173957L, 172656L, 171951L, 52728L, 52257L, 51756L, 
    693878L, 690566L, 689434L, 39168L, 39171L, 38881L, 131255L, 
    131094L, 131507L, 35590L, 35564L, 35484L, 83226L, 83459L, 
    83741L, 786189L, 790201L, 787808L, 303905L, 301876L, 299715L, 
    63831L, 63217L, 62389L, 664953L, 661108L, 664938L, 84263L, 
    84519L, 84959L, 85584L, 86026L, 86120L), `Esfuerzo Social` = c(12353570.26, 
    10922141.66, 11450013.65, 15963858.06, 16781422.67, 18298031.66, 
    14867434.39, 14500734.62, 13157434.34, 9458354.23, 9271539.84, 
    5621106.01, 5544874.22, 6009806.4, 28499840.09, 28263531.47, 
    30747350.88, 269377354.25, 269687878.57, 311009897.1, 9847253.6, 
    11682897.44, 11662432.69, 3516333, 3854313.85, 3987239.66, 
    15119782.93, 15223387.62, 15573839.74, 10220700.43, 10884960.63, 
    12003103.14, 4305129.22, 4493823.61, 4729076.99, 32917425.6, 
    28064436.03, 32559749.92, 21302157.38, 20479378.22, 22499515.58, 
    2361489.1, 2696353.37, 2117289.71, 9988574.72, 10042995.31, 
    9088724.66, 23212458.85, 23928882.64, 25312197.83, 3515746.67, 
    3704068.37, 3603573.47, 11779688.78, 12099911.63, 9753172.03, 
    2535171.2, 2794195.55, 2745971.76, 11087890.83, 12657489.6, 
    11741169.23, 9633918.63, 10653275.15, 10250409.9, 21627620.03, 
    11339588.65, 11976310.93, 11678201.27, 11588866.11, 12508845.41, 
    6354079.57, 7251694.22, 6295505.75, 319002813.85, 336765246.88, 
    370002842.09, 48087330.09, 50183361.26, 54310973, 23936966.64, 
    25208156.09, 25674095.7, 6591149.97, 5163582.52, 7913419.45, 
    14263042.19, 16110379.54, 16524331.3, 5235375.12, 5385022.46, 
    5707501.06, 45499446.01, 43516030.57, 49626117.33, 2965094.16, 
    2918548.92, 3097844.98, 9098495.22, 9690902.6, 10244355.63, 
    18086427.14, 20809565.23, 24383554.51, 7703290.38, 7333144.4, 
    9699415.62, 3539691, 3851895.54, 3960011.56, 59275193.9, 
    61950362.27, 70918490.64, 6175033.34, 6321130.67, 6062631.85, 
    11165492.12, 11904640.63, 12632395.97, 1763313.67, 1873380.28, 
    2023896.31, 3468411.84, 3589493.14, 3626506.31, 56736581.32, 
    59832670.73, 65963215.33, 21597101.58, 19558134.83, 20634437.72, 
    2780114.43, 3145283.83, 3617142.22, 69832389.44, 74653628.26, 
    75028650.45, 14000344.92, 15119434.03, 16073267.92, 32076143.64, 
    35012561.82, 37133673.83), `Esfuerzo Total` = c(146336577.74, 
    144001222.43, 146900702.41, 274437886.16, 255653667.86, 242141152.77, 
    170271509.03, 158297508.18, 158339559.37, 51025307.05, 51162661.04, 
    104635468.81, 129356260.33, 93091788.49, 403776960.41, 406988326.44, 
    442573789.35, 2863263170.77, 2776640464.76, 2767429667.27, 
    181895321.7, 177179557.98, 197229750.4, 67550236.14, 65487414.2, 
    72604676.71, 154741114.03, 147976479.38, 145095608.88, 148452089.03, 
    152564946.94, 178543220.9, 64040880.16, 64745398.16, 76024274.27, 
    291746009.37, 269000136.8, 305747034.65, 238591283.22, 217199329.97, 
    227447212.74, 55210772.61, 53350392.52, 48751853.68, 118976936.23, 
    117997137.22, 113432066.54, 260474161.15, 258739020.49, 274200741.57, 
    78113679.24, 63774425.87, 64507652.1, 106752012.11, 109322964.15, 
    119384591.53, 54951779.85, 45192599.75, 48202704.12, 156066667.24, 
    118250506.52, 130151785.6, 124751717.72, 139513886.58, 134829503.35, 
    153572785.3, 149440154.19, 152315670.12, 135149127.56, 130898825.25, 
    135870513.69, 84335771.96, 88028341.41, 76076444.14, 4409536506.99, 
    4788757430.06, 4257036746.64, 583751792.77, 614977804.71, 
    608574263.8, 381446450.71, 380020463.64, 363999558.04, 107553442.94, 
    96407948.9, 92771997.68, 205957732.52, 195377347.73, 238110024.4, 
    68218816.99, 63993765.55, 67694380.74, 305535009.3, 303136532.22, 
    327379174.56, 68298349.95, 68121278.49, 66693094.61, 150082935.78, 
    140176815.87, 142200689.59, 200250522.69, 204588380.34, 203382556.79, 
    174179813.47, 172366586.82, 192494726.65, 57978774.97, 64477788.36, 
    63425075.01, 739698610.72, 738936525.09, 734690074.96, 47428843.58, 
    37703999.81, 38006349.91, 161231015.95, 180820707.05, 170924880.92, 
    29352061.33, 26507583.53, 29132086.12, 105104293.36, 89009650.48, 
    88363542.15, 1001956983.6, 747514692.26, 770687365.33, 265003928.39, 
    246596858, 261926908.17, 50666451.54, 57176567.76, 52564110.51, 
    754417763.41, 687977382.66, 734538384.99, 275230668.17, 254832077.57, 
    253416368.24, 240640468.48, 239046287.37, 249139842.84)), row.names = c(NA, 
143L), class = "data.frame")
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

De tal manera que pueda presentar una tabla donde para cada una de esas variables `Población` `Esfuerzo Social` `Esfuerzo Total` se presente una columna de cada año.

Aunque rmarkdown no lo pueda representar sería algo así:

```
            |Población           |Esfuerzo Social     |Esfuerzo Total      |
            |--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
            ||2015| |2016| |2017|||2015| |2016| |2017|||2015| |2016| |2017||
            ||----| |----| |----|||----| |----| |----|||----| |----| |----||
|Municipio| ||    | |    | |    |||    | |    | |    |||    | |    | |    ||
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si entendí bien tu problema podrías aplicar la siguiente función para pivotear las columnas deseadas:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = pivot_wider(df,
  names_from = c("Año"),
  values_from = c("Población", "Esfuerzo Social", "Esfuerzo Total")
  )
```

Es decir, tu df se pivoteara respecto a la variable "Año" y los valores serán obtenidos de las variables "Población", "Esfuerzo Social", "Esfuerzo Total"
para cada categoria que contenga tu variable "Año"

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, he actualizado la pregunta, necesito que para cada una de las variables `Población` `Esfuerzo Social` y `Esfuerzo total` las pueda mostrar en una tabla donde para cada una de ellas se presente una columna por año.

Comment: Sí, como has respondido, sería una opción el código de tu respuesta, indicando también, id_cols:
df <- pivot_wider (
          data = df,
          id_cols = c("Municipio"),
          names_from = c("Año"),
          values_from = c("Población", "Esfuerzo Social", "Esfuerzo Total")
        )

Comment: Para el ejemplo que he propuesto, el resultado es el mismo sin definir id_cols. Es una opción válida como solución.